# Checkboxes count not updating

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm finally getting around to learning jQuery and just when I start to think I'm getting the hang of things, I get stuck again.

I have a script that counts the number of checked check boxes in a section. 
If the section reaches a limit, prevents user from making more selections and gives them a message, but should allow them to deselect other check boxes.

I have this working EXCEPT, when they deselect a check box, the error message pops up again, as it's still counting the previous number of check boxes. How do I update the count correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/MadHatrix/VxscW/3/

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
    <button class="btn-option">1</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-checkbox" />
    <button class="btn-option">2</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-checkbox" />
    <button class="btn-option">3</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-checkbox" />
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="btn-option">a</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-checkbox" />
    <button class="btn-option">b</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-checkbox" />
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.panel').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).next('input:checkbox');
    var checkedTotal = $(this).parent('.panel').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    if (checkedTotal == 2) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        alert('limit has been reached');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need check if this(clicked) checkbox already checked or not. If already checked then you need decrement the checkedTotal since this checkbox will be uncheck.

try this:

```
$('.panel').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).next('input:checkbox');
    var checkedTotal = $(this).parent('.panel').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        checkedTotal =checkedTotal -1;
    }
    if (checkedTotal == 2) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        alert('limit has been reached');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
       checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxscW/4/)